# SQL Server - Protect records from modification if condition is true

Tags: sql-server

It may be a stupid question but is there any possibility to prevent a row/record from modification if some condition applied is true in MSSQL Server?

For example:

I have a document with 5 lines. The information of the whole document are stored in two tables (DocumentHeader and DocumentLines, linked through FK_documentGUID). I use an export scenario at lines level and after one line is exported in a text delimited file with all the information, it is marked with 1 (Exported). Can I use something in SQL that will check the line if it was exported and if so, to freeze/block/validate the line from furher modifications. Thanks!

Comment: Create ExportedLines table with FK_documentGUID | lineNumber and read/write to that to track status?

Comment: It sounds like an `INSTEAD OF DELETE Trigger` could do the job: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191208(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Can you post the schemas of the tables involved? From your question it's not obvious how you can tell that a row you are inserting is the same as an existing row. I can't see how you would use the Exported field. Surely you are matching something else that tells you this row exists?